# bash aliases с аргументом

Tags: bash, alias

Есть функция для создания репозитория

repo() {
    curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"имя репозитория"}'
}

хочу передать параметр $1 вместо имени репозитория, пробовал "name":"\"$1\""}'. Не работает. Подскажите как мне правильно это сделать. Спасибо

Comment: `'{"name":"'"$1"'"}'`?

Comment: Угу да, работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующая конструкция:

```sh
'{"name":"'"$1"'"}'
```

Работает так:

```
'{"name":"'"$1"'"}'
^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^ -- буквальные строки
           ^^^^     -- экранированное разыменование первого
                       аргумента
```